# Amazon Route 53 Resolves mydomain.com but not www.mydomain.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have an Amazon Route 53 policy pointing my domain name to elastic beanstalk. If I type mydomain.com into my browser, it works fine. However, if I type www.mydomain.com into my browser then my browser cannot find my domain. The start point DNS type is set as "A: IP address in IPv4 format" and that points to elastic beanstalk. The policy record is under mydomain.com rather than www.mydomain.com. How do I get it to resolve both correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Route 53 -> Hosted Zones -> Your Website -> Create Record Set, and then create a CNAME record with name: www.mydomain.com and value: mydomain.com.